# LyX: Предпросмотр математики

Tags: lyx

В **Инструменты>Настройки>Вид** вторым сверху стоит один [раскрывающийся список][1]. В зависимости от используемого файла `.mo` в русском переводе названий элементов интерфейса он имеет различные названия. В той копии программы LyX, которую я использовал до этого, он назывался, если я не ошибаюсь, *Предпросмотр математики*. В текущей копии программы LyX он называется *Instant Preview*. Что это такое?

Answer (score 0):

А суть его в следующем. Если я установлю значение этого списка в *выкл*, то после выхода курсора из математического (строковой формулы) или выклочного режима формула в окне LyX выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А при значении этого списка *вкл* формула начинает выглядеть вот как:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но само по себе это представляет мало интереса. Гораздо интереснее выглядит использование этого раскрывающегося списка вместе со счетчиком *Preview Size*. Именно, установим значение выпадающего списка в *вкл*, а значение счетчика в какое-нибудь значение, большее 1, например, 3,8, нажимаем кнопку `Сохранить`. Тогда после перезапуска LyX формулы начинают отображаться следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот это уже кое-что. Я это использовал, например, когда расписывал многоэтажные дробные показатели степеней при изучении доказательства одной теоремы теории групп: от руки получалось запутанно, а в LyX с использованием этой примочки получилось в самый раз.